# Decoding Holding Registers to binary format

Tags: python, pymodbus

Need help decoding storage registers to binary format. When reading, I get a value from 8 to 15 bits. I can't read the value from 0 to 7 bits, I want to count bits 0-15 as a request, but 8-15 comes in. What am I doing wrong?
I tried different combinations of register polling:

```
(res5.registers, Endian.Big, Endian.Big).decode_bits
(res5.registers, Endian.Little, Endian.Big).decode_bits
(res5.registers, Endian.Little, Endian.Little).decode_bits
```

Modbus Slave: ID:1 F:03
0: -47,2 (float32)
1:
2: -7565 (int)
3: -3 (int)
4: 4581 (uint)
5: 5555 (uint)
6: 67 (uint)
7: 76 (uint)
8: 0000 0001 0101 1001 (bool)
9: 0000 0100 0110 0011 (bool)

Versions
Python: 3.9.1
OS: Windows 10 Pro 2004
Pymodbus: 2.5.1, Client: RTU

```
# code

   from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient
    from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
    from pymodbus.constants import Endian
    
    client = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu', port='COM5', baudrate=19200, timeout=3, parity='N', stopbits=1, bytesize=8)
    
    if client.connect():
        res1 = client.read_holding_registers(0, 10, unit=1)
        res2 = client.read_holding_registers(0, 2, unit=1)
        res3 = client.read_holding_registers(2, 1, unit=1)
        res4 = client.read_holding_registers(3, 1, unit=1)
        res5 = client.read_holding_registers(8, 1, unit=1)
        if not res3.isError():
            print(res1)
            print(res1.registers)
            print("-" * 60)
            print(BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(res2.registers, Endian.Big, Endian.Big).decode_32bit_float())
            print(BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(res3.registers, Endian.Big, Endian.Little).decode_16bit_int())
            print(BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(res4.registers, Endian.Big, Endian.Little).decode_16bit_int())
            print(BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(res5.registers, Endian.Big, Endian.Little).decode_bits())
        else:
            print(res3, 'Error')
            # print('\n')
        print("-" * 60)
    else:
        print('Cannot connect Modbus Server/Slave')
```

## logs

> ### ReadHoldingRegistersResponse (10) [49724, 52429, 57971, 65533, 4581,
> 5555, 67, 76, 345, 1123]
>
> ### -47.20000076293945
> -7565
> -3 [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Hello, I did not get what you are trying to do from your question. Can you maybe point to the Modbus map of the device you are trying to read from?. Be aware that all decoders in pymodbus will discard anything exceeding the size they expect to receive. So, for instance, you should only do `.decode_32bit_float()` on two registers. If you include more than 32 bits (two registers) all others but the first two will be discarded.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am trying to read from register 8 of function 3 (40009) the binary status 0000 0001 0101 1001. But when requesting `BinaryPayloadDecoder. fromRegisters(client.read_holding_registers(8, 1, unit=1).registers, Endian.Big,Endian.Little).decode_bits())` I get 0000 0001 [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]. How do I get the remaining 8 bits?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments I'm not completely sure I understand what your problem is.

But focusing on how to get the whole 16-bit register using `decode_bits()` what you can do is the following:

```
# First read the register:
reg = client.read_holding_registers(8, 1, unit=1)

# Then instantiate your decoder with the right configuration
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(reg,Endian.Big,Endian.Little)

# And now do the decoding, first 8 bits:
bits_in_reg = decoder.decode_bits()

# And 8 bits more, note the += to keep and shift the bits you just read
bits_in_reg += decoder.decode_bits()
```

Does it make more sense the way you are trying to do it? I guess... but the `decode_bits()` function is implemented to read words (8 bit chunks) and not registers

I'm adding an example here for completeness. If I define `regs=[128,129]` this is what I get after running the code above:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True]
```

If I call `decoder.decode_bits()` two additional times I get this:

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True]
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried another solution, but yours is certainly more correct. Thanks!
BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(res.registers, Endian.Big, Endian.Little).decode_16bit_int() & 0b0000000000000001) > 0
BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(res.registers, Endian.Big, Endian.Little).decode_16bit_int() & 0b0000000000000010) > 0
BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(res.registers, Endian.Big, Endian.Little).decode_16bit_int() & 0b0000000000000100) > 0 BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(res.registers, Endian.Big, Endian.Little).decode_16bit_int() & 0b0000000000001000) > 0)

Comment: # And 8 bits more, note the += to keep and shift the bits you just read
bits_in_reg += decoder.decode_bits() 

Unfortunately, this way the first request is duplicated, the missing flags are not received

Comment: I will double-check it

Comment: I've added an example, is that not what you get if you run the code above?

Comment: The tests were never successful. Could you tell us how to use a bit mask and a loop to convert an integer of 16 bits into an array [True, False, etc...]? Maybe there is a link